# Estimate of $\sigma^2$ in a simple linear regression when $H_0: \beta = 0$ is true

Tags: regression, variance, residuals

I was reading some lecture notes on simple linear regression where one section said that when the slope is 0 (hence, $H_0: \beta = 0$ is actually true), $\frac{(SSY - SSE)}{(DFY - DFE)}$ estimates sigma squared. This doesn't make sense to me. If beta is actually 0, then shouldn't SSY and SSE be the same value?

$$SSY = ∑(Y-\bar{Y})^2$$
$$SSE = ∑(Y-\hat{Y})^2$$

However, if $\beta = 0$, that means the best estimate ($\widehat{\text{Y}}$) is essentially $\overline{\text{Y}}$, which in turn means

$$SSY = SSE =  ∑(Y-\bar{Y})^2$$

In other words

$$\frac{SSY - SSE}{DFY - DFE} = \frac{0}{DFY - DFE}$$

Is there something that I am missing? I hope someone here can elaborate on this.

Comment: Are you able to post a copy of the lecture notes, or link to them?

Comment: SSY = SSE if $\hat{\beta} = 0$, which is not the same as $\beta=0$.  Randomness of the residual guarantees, in the case of continuous residuals, that $\hat{\beta}$ won't actually equal 0 even when $\beta=0$..

Comment: @jbowman Thanks. But if at the same time SSE/DFE also estimates sigma^2, then my question is how is SSE/DFE = (SSY - SSE)/(DFY - DEF).

Comment: Max There is no further explanation. The text is basically when beta=0, (SSY - SSE)/(DFY - DFE) estimates sigma^2.

Comment: I've edited your post to include LATEX formatting. Please double check that it still says what you want.

Comment: The point that @jbowman is trying to make is that $\hat{Y}$ is a function of $\hat{\beta}$ NOT $\beta$, so even though you are confident that $\beta=0$, that doesn't mean $\hat{\beta}$ is 0 (it will probably be close, but not exact.)